# Where should I wait for threads completion in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

Where should I wait for threads completion in WinForms application? `FormClosed` / `FormClosing` events? Which one is the best for this task?

I have a task that periodically checks some files and make HTTP requests to some site. This it the main form of my application. The task is cancellable so I want to interrupt it and wait some time to finish.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        deviceDetectionTask = new CancellableTask(() => DeviceDetection());
    }

    // ...

    private CancellableTask deviceDetectionTask;
}

public class CancellableTask
{
    public CancellableTask(Action action)
    {
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(action, ts.Token);
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        ts.Cancel();
    }

    private CancellationTokenSource ts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private Task task;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What thread? To do what? What do you want to do and why? What have you tried and how did it not live up to your expectations?

Comment: @kai Updated the question

Comment: This is a very vague question and it's hard to give any form of definitive answer. In general (assuming long-running worker threads) my personal preference is to wait in `FormClosing` because the close operation can be cancelled there. It needs some tricky logic to avoid blocking the UI and turn it into an all-white window.

Comment: This depends on what your threads are doing, but from a UI standpoint it's bad practice to tie up the GUI thread at any point, for any reason.  It's much better to make sure that your threads are cancellable, then show a progress bar with a cancel button and disable any UI elements that you don't want the user to interact with while the threads are running.

Comment: @adv12 That's good advice but I think the OP is asking about threads that are running when the user clicks the `X` button to close the main application window.

Comment: Which form? Which instance of the form?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Updated. Main Form

Comment: @adv12 Updated. Yes, this task is cancellable

Comment: Is it truely a `Task` or is it a thread with some kind of cancellation flag? I would suggest changing over to a `Task` which can be cancelled and waited upon easily, with timeouts. Without seeing your "task" its hard to tell you how or where it should be stopped.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Updated the question

Comment: Unfortunately you are using cancellation tokens wrong, I can't see the code for your `DeviceDetection` but it should take the token as an argument and periodically call the `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` method, or check the cancellation flags on the token. Otherwise your action isn't going to respond to the cancellation request.

Comment: A very essential detail is missing: does the task interact with the UI at all?  A crucial detail since, if that's the case, waiting for the task to complete will almost always cause deadlock.  You cannot wait and must prevent the form from closing with OnFormClosing.  And close, later, when you know the task actually completed.  If on the other hand no such interaction occurs then you just don't care and simply call Cancel() anywhere you like, OnFormClosed being the obvious place.

Answer (score 1):

Without really trying to go into details given only to choose from two:

> `FormClosed` / `FormClosing` events? Which one is the best for this task?

[`FormClosed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closed(v=vs.110).aspx), is *semantically* better, because

> You can use this event to perform tasks such as freeing resources used by the form and to save information entered in the form or to update its parent form.

In `FormClosing` you may decide to prevent closing.

Note:

> The Form.Closed and Form.Closing events are not raised when the Application.Exit method is called to exit your application. If you have validation code in either of these events that must be executed, you should call the Form.Close method for each open form individually before calling the Exit method